# Is there a way to make a discord bot detect if the author of the command is on a certain server? discord.js

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a Bug report command that send me an email with the bug report (works good), but I want that the person that use were on the support server to contact him if I need more information. Is there any way to a discord bot detect if a user is in a certain server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at all the guilds the bot is in using `client.guilds.cache` and check if the user you want is in one or more of those guilds using `guild.member()`.

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
            const member = guild.member(args[0]);
            if (member !== null) {
            message.channel.send(`${member!.guild.name} (ID: ${member!.guild.id})`);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for checking the server when a user executes a command, you can just use `message.channel.guild.id`, which returns the ID of the server the command was used in. You can then compare it to a specific server ID.

Comment: No, I want that the command could be executed in any server, but the autor must be in the support server to use it.

Comment: Yes, but I need that the command knows if the user is in a specific server, not if it is being executed in a specific server.